# How can I change my PyPI username?

Tags: python, pypi

I'd like to change my username on http://pypi.python.org to "rebrand" some packages I've developed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 16):

What you actually need to do is change the *ownership* of your packages.

To do this, you need to follow these steps:

1. Create an account for the new owner.
2. Under the old account, view the package page, and click `roles`.
3. Add your new user account as an owner:

   1. Enter your **new** account name under `Username`
   2. Set the `Role to add` as `Owner`
   3. Click `Add Role`
4. Verify that the ownership has been moved by logging in under the new account. You should see the package listed under 'your packages' in the sidebar.
5. View the package page again while still in the new owner's account and click `roles`.
6. Remove the old account:

   1. Enter your **old** account name under `Username`
   2. Click `Remove Role`

You can then log back in under your old account to verify that ownership has been changed, should you wish.